# OsmDroid switch online/offline provider

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am using OsmDroid to display both online and offline data in my app. The offline data are stored in a .sqlite file.

The default use is online and MapView work well:

```
m_mapView = new MapView(inflater.Context);
var tileSource = TileSourceFactory.GetTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DefaultTileSource.Name());
m_mapView.SetUseDataConnection(true);
m_mapView.TilesScaledToDpi = true;
m_mapView.SetTileSource(tileSource);
```

To switch to offline mode I try this and work well:

```
OfflineTileProvider m_OfflineTileProvider = new OfflineTileProvider(new SimpleRegisterReceiver(Activity), new File[] { f });
m_mapView.TileProvider = m_OfflineTileProvider;

string source = "";
IArchiveFile[] archives = m_OfflineTileProvider.GetArchives();
if (archives.Length > 0)
{
    List<string> tileSources = archives[0].TileSources.ToList<string>();
    if (tileSources.Count > 0)
    {
        m_mapView.SetUseDataConnection(false);
        source = tileSources[0];
        ITileSource tilesource = FileBasedTileSource.GetSource(source);
        if (tilesource != null)
            this.m_mapView.SetTileSource(tilesource);
        else
            this.m_mapView.SetTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DefaultTileSource);
    }
    else
    {
        this.m_mapView.SetTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DefaultTileSource);
    }

}
else
    this.m_mapView.SetTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DefaultTileSource);
```

The problem is to return to online mode:

```
var tileSource = TileSourceFactory.GetTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DefaultTileSource.Name());
m_mapView.SetUseDataConnection(true);
m_mapView.SetTileSource(tileSource);
```

I don't have errors, but I don't see Tiles. I see only the grid lines and gray background

How can I use online and offline provider ?